# use of for-loops in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am stuck with my homework (I am a complete beginner), where the output should be **a square with diagonals (composed of stars)**, the rest composed of minus signs. The side of the square is determined by the user's input, which should be an `odd number >=1` (here scanner used).

Only for-`loops` and `if` statements should be used.

With my code I only manage to get one diagonal. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int laenge=0;
    do {
    System.out.printf(": ");
    laenge =sc.nextInt(); 
    }while(laenge%2 == 0);


    for(int i=1;i<=laenge;i++){
        for (int j=1; j<=laenge; j++) {
            if (i==j)
                System.out.print("*");
            else
                System.out.print("-");
        }
        for (int j=laenge;j<=1; j--) {
            if (i==j)
                System.out.print("*");
            else
                System.out.print("-");
        }

        System.out.println();
        }       

    sc.close();
```

Comment: it is working as you said, what is wrong.

Comment: You don't need two loops over j. Just print the star if `i == j || i+j == laenge+1`. (Also, your second loop over j will not execute anyway unless `laenge == 1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   for(int i=1;i<=laenge;i++){

        for (int j=1; j<=laenge; j++) {

            if (i==j||(i+j)==(laenge+1))
                System.out.print("*");
            else
                System.out.print("-");
        }
```

You just need to do this. For first diagonal (i==j), for second diagnonal the sum of i&j will be equal to (laenge+1).